# GoogleSheets ApsScript ReferenceError: ADDRESS is not definedDetails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the following code snippet there is a very simple code.
When I try to use  it I'm getting

> ReferenceError: ADDRESS is not defined error.

I'll appreciate very much if someone could shed a light on this issue.

```
function temp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(ADDRESS(15,D1)).activate;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**Issue 1:**

- [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en) is a google sheets function but you are trying to use it in Google Apps Script.

The latter does not accept google sheets formulas. It has its own [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and only `JavaScript` is supported.

**Issue 2:**

To execute a function in any programming language you need to add parentheses at the end of the function. Replace `activate` with `activate()`.

**Solution:**

You most likely want to take the range of cell `D15`. If that's the case then simply do:

```
function temp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D15').activate();
};
```

Keep in mind this will work for the active sheet only (the sheet that is currently selected). If you want to select a specific sheet by its name, then do that and change `Sheet1` to the sheet name of your choice:

```
function temp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1') // put the sheet name of your choice
  sheet.getRange('D15').activate();
};
```

**Updated answer based on your comment:**

Assuming cell `D15` contains a cell reference of the cell you want to activate, then do that:

```
function temp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1') // put the sheet name of your choice
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getRange('D15').getValue()).activate();
};
```

or based on your original code:

```
function temp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getRange('D15').getValue()).activate();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 
I ask the question in mature. I want to create indirectly a adress . The D!5 cell contains an adrress for getRange.

Comment: @SabetayToros so as far as I understand. Cell `D15` has a value and that value is the cell reference of another cell? For example the value of `D15` is let's say `A12` ?

Comment: You nailed it. Exactly this is the question

Comment: @SabetayToros see "Updated answer based on your comment" in my answer. Confirm if that worked for you :)

Comment: Thanks. I could not imagine this. It is a light. Thanks

Comment: I did it. Thank you for your warning

Comment: @SabetayToros apparently you didn't. Here is how you can do it: [How do I accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)